# Qual a função do ponto e vírgula em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Encontrei alguns códigos que tinham variáveis dentro de classes, terminadas em ponto e vírgula. Não entendi o por que, e também não encontrei na internet algo sobre isso.

```
    class exemplo():

      self.variavel_teste = 0;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ele só é necessário se você quiser colocar um comando extra na mesma linha, então ele funciona como separador de comandos. Obviamente é permitido colocá-lo e em seguida deixar nada, o que faz parecer como um terminador igual do C e suas descendentes. De fato é um terminador, mas opcional em quase todas situações. E neste caso específico parece abuso do recurso.

Isto é chamado [*compound statements*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html).

```
x = 5; print(x);
if x > 0: print("maior que zero"); print(x);
```

É o mesmo que

```
x = 5
print(x)
if x > 0:
    print("maior que zero")
    print(x)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8nQ6rB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dfyjgshi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Semicolon.py).

Comment: O mesmo acontece no Ruby. Só que lá fazemos para métodos sem definição, geralmente, que no Python utilizaria o `pass`, por exemplo. Em Ruby: `def method; end`

Answer (score 15):

No exemplo, para nada.

Ele pode ser utilizado, obrigatoriamente, para separar expressões em uma mesma linha e, opcionalmente, ao final dela:

```
a = 1; b = 2

print(a+b)  # 3
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ElaborateChillyCryptocurrency)</sup>

Porém isso, geralmente, acaba afetando a legibilidade e no Python ela <s>quase</s> sempre é priorizada, então dificilmente você utilizará o ponto-e-vírgula.

Na [gramática do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) há previsto:

```
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
```

Onde uma `simple_stmt` é composta de uma `small_stmt`, podendo ser seguida de inúmeras outras `small_stmt` separadas pelo ponto-e-vírgula, com o caractere sendo opcional no final, antes da quebra de linha.

No seu exemplo, só existe uma expressão que precede o caractere, então ele não teve utilidade alguma.